# Version of citet without author-year style?

Tags: macros, bibliographies, bibtex, citing, authoryear

I'm wondering if it's possible to hack my own version of `citet` that works even for numerical reference styles.

Basically what I want is for `\citet{foo}` to result in `AuthorName~\cite{foo}` i.e. look up the author name(s) from the bibliography, print it, and then print a numerical citation as usual.

Is this possible? I'm basically trying to manage the situation where I have a large document that was made in author-year format, without having to go and manually write out the author names.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Any numerical style that is `natbib`-compatible (e.g. `unsrtnat`) will already support this with `\citet`, `biblatex` also supports this. How are you currently generating your bibliography?

Comment: @DaiBowen I'm using the LIPIcs template which, unfortunately, explicitly doesn't support natbib: https://www.dagstuhl.de/en/publishing/series/details/LIPIcs

Answer (score 1):

`\citet` will work already with numerical [`natbib`](https://ctan.org/pkg/natbib)-compatible styles

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\citet{article-full}

\bibliography{xampl}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

as will [`biblatex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) with the `natbib` option

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\citet{aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

However bibtex doesn't otherwise expose anything apart from the `.bbl` so to write your own function is not simply a TeX problem but would involve parsing the `.bib` file as well as the `.tex` or `.aux` file. [`usebib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/usebib) is probably the closest entity which exists but would still require some non-trivial parsing of the author field at the least.

In this case you are required to use `plainurl.bst` which seems to be a lightly modified form of `plain` to be compatible with URLs
[image: Reference list of LIPICs sample article]
[`natbib`](https://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) has its own version of `plain` (`plainnat`), which is also URL/DOI-compatible, and is similar but not identical when used in the same template
[image: Reference list of LIPICs sample article with natbib and plainnat]
The DOIs appearance should be easily patchable with `\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\path{doi:#1}}` but other aspects (I think modified due to the loading of [`natbib`](https://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) itself) would need to patched to match the appearance.
The `.bbl` files generated (which may be what the publisher is more concerned about, though if so they might also baulk at an unfamiliar `\citet`) are also similar but not identical.

As an individual author it's unlikely anything is more time-efficient than hardcoding `AuthorName~\cite{foo}`, or writing `\citet{foo}` and regex-ing that to substitute `AuthorName~\cite{foo}` upon submission.